# Spring boot only uses primary datasource with two datasources

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have two MySQL datasources in Spring Boot, therefore I have two config classes. But it looks like its only using the primary datasource. All entities are created for the primary datasource, so both crawlerdb and userdb entities are created in the userdb.

My userdb primary config:

```
/**
 * Data source for the MySQL User Database schema
 */
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.domain.userdb")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.repos.userdb")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class UserDomainConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.users")
    public DataSourceProperties userDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.users.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource firstDataSource(DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties) {
        return firstDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

}
```

My secondary crawlerdb config:

```
/**
 * Data source for the MySQL crawler database schema
 */
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.domain.crawlerdb")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.repos.crawlerdb")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CrawlerDomainConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.crawler")
    public DataSourceProperties crawlerDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.crawler.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource secondDataSource(DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties) {
        return secondDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

}
```

The entity classes for both schema's are in different packages as shown in `@EntityScan` above the class name. But when I check MySQL workbench for the created schema's I see that all entities are created in the userdb.

Comment: `All entities are created for the primary datasource` that is expected behavior. If you want your services to use distinct datasources you have to explicitly autowire them into  those services.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issues by changing the config files like this aticle:

https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/